# Como concatenar cadeias de um vetor de 3 em 3 em Java?

Tags: java, array

Preciso de concatenar os elementos de um vetor de 3 em 3.

Segue a amostra do que preciso:

```
package ex;

public class prog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] vetor = {"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd", "ddd"};

String[] novo_vetor; // vetor que terá as strings "aaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbb", "ccccccccc", "ddddddddd");
    }

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] vetor = {"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd", "ddd"};
        String[] novoVetor = new String[vetor.length / 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i += 3) novoVetor[i / 3] = vetor[i] + vetor[i + 1] + vetor[i + 2];
        for (String item : novoVetor) System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Jm7XuI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/stkdkrli-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Concat3x3.java).